# Override SessionsController to refuse access based on user attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-token-auth

I have a rails 4 project, where I'm using DeviseTokenAuth.
Everything works fine, but I'd like to refuse access to user with a specific status.
So basically

```
if user.status == :locked => Account :unauthorized
```

So this is what I've done so far

```
class SessionsController < DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController
   def new
      super
   end

   def create
      super
      render json: { error: "Account is locked MOFO " }, status: :unauthorized if current_user.status.to_sym == :locked    
    end
end
```

But when I do that I get :

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError - Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please notethat you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".:
```

Any idea ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens because double render methods are called from sessions controller create method. One option is to override `render_create_success` method to get the desired result.

```
class SessionsController < DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController

   protected

   def render_create_success
    if current_user.status.to_sym == :locked
      render json: { error: "Account is locked MOFO " }, status: :unauthorized
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```